# Why my program stops running after detaching from shared memory when i added som code

Tags: c, linux, semaphore, shared-memory

I have a program that creates two processes. The first one gets a command-line argument provided by the user and sends it via shared memory to the second process.  The second process has to interpret the argument as a file name and check the permissions of the designated file. But after passing the directory to second process my program hangs.  What's wrong with it?

```
#include <unistd.h>     // fork
#include <stdio.h>      // printf
#include <sys/ipc.h>        // ftok
#include <sys/sem.h>        // operacje na semaforach
#include <stdlib.h>     // exit
#include <err.h>            // errx
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SHM_SIZE     1024
/* plik, w ktorym bedziemy zapisywali dane. */
#define buffer "test"

/* unia dla semafora */
union semun {
    int val;                                // wartosc dla SETVAL
    struct semid_ds *buf;               // bufor dla IPC_STAT, IPC_SET
    unsigned short int *array;      // tablica dla GETALL, SETALL
    struct seminfo *__buf;          // bufor dla IPC_INFO
};


/* blokowanie semafora */
int semlock(int semid) {

    /* Struktura opisujaca operacje na semaforach */
    struct sembuf opr;
    /* podgld struktury z opisem pol:
         struct sembuf {
            ushort semnum;
            short sem_op;
            ushort sem_flg;
        };
    *
    * gdzie:
    *   semnum - numer semafora,
    *   sem_op - operacja na semaforze:
    *       sem_op > 0 - (V) zwiekszenie semafora o wartosc "sem_op"
    *       sem_op < 0 - (P) polozenie semafora (wstrzymanie procesu)
    *                    lub zmniejszenie semafora o wartosc "sem_op"
    *       sem_op = 0 - (Z) "przejscie pod semaforem", odwrotnosc (P)
    */

    opr.sem_num =  0;
    opr.sem_op  = -1;        // blokowanie
    opr.sem_flg =  0;        // operacja blokujaca

    if (semop(semid, &opr, 1) == -1){
        warn("Blad blokowania semafora!");
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}


/* odblokowanie semafora */
int semunlock(int semid) {

    /* Struktura opisujaca operacje na semaforach */
    struct sembuf opr;

    opr.sem_num = 0;
    opr.sem_op  = 1;
    opr.sem_flg = 0;

    if (semop(semid, &opr, 1) == -1){
        warn("Blad odblokowania semafora!");
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    key_t key1, key2;           // klucz dla semaforow
    int   semid1, semid2;   // ID semaforow
    union semun ctl;            // unia do kontroli semafora
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/


    /*****************************************************************/
    /* Tworzymy klucz dla semafora I */
    if ((key1 = ftok(".", 'A')) == -1)
        errx(1, "Blad tworzenia klucza!");

    /* Pobieramy ID semafora. Jesli semafor nie istnieje - tworzymy. */
    /*           semget(klucz, liczba semaforow, flagi/parametry) */
    if ((semid1 = semget(key1, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1)
        errx(2, "Blad tworzenia semafora!");

    /* Inicjujemy semafor I jako podniesiony (S = 1). */
    ctl.val = 1;
    if (semctl(semid1, 0, SETVAL, ctl) == -1)
        errx(3, "Blad ustawiania semafora!");

    /*****************************************************************/
    /* Tworzymy klucz dla semafora II */
    if ((key2 = ftok(".", 'B')) == -1)
        errx(1, "Blad tworzenia klucza!");

    /* Pobieramy ID semafora. Jesli semafor nie istnieje - tworzymy. */
    /*           semget(klucz, liczba semaforow, flagi/parametry) */
    if ((semid2 = semget(key2, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1)
        errx(2, "Blad tworzenia semafora!");

    /* Inicjujemy semafor II jako podniesiony (S = 1). */
    ctl.val = 1;
    if (semctl(semid2, 0, SETVAL, ctl) == -1)
        errx(3, "Blad ustawiania semafora!");
    /*****************************************************************/

    /* Blokujemy semafor procesu, ktory nie powinien wystartowac pierwszy */
    semlock(semid2);

    if(fork()){ //proces 1

            /* proces blokuje swoj semafor */
            semlock(semid1);

        // ftok to generate unique key
        key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65);

        // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
        int shmid = shmget(key,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT);

        // shmat to attach to shared memory
        char *str = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);

        sleep(1);
        strcpy(str,argv[1]);

        printf("Data written in memory: %s\n",str);

        //detach from shared memory
        shmdt(str);


            sleep(1);

            /* Odblokowujemy semafor drugiemu procesowi */
            semunlock(semid2);

    }else{ //proces 2

            semlock(semid2);    //proces blokuje swoj semafor -



        // ftok to generate unique key
        key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65);

        // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
        int shmid = shmget(key,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT);

        // shmat to attach to shared memory
        char *str = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);
        char *sciezka;
        printf("Data read from memory: %s\n",str);
        strcpy(sciezka,str);
        //detach from shared memory
        shmdt(str);
        // destroy the shared memory
        semunlock(semid2);


        printf("Data : %s\n",sciezka);



        FILE *fptr;
        struct stat info;
        if ( !( fptr = fopen( sciezka, "r" ))){
            printf( "Plik nie zostal otwarty poniewaz nie istnieje\n" );
        }
        else {
            fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
            unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(fptr);
            if (len > 0) {  //sprawdza czy plik jest pusty czy nie
                printf("Podany plik nie jest pusty.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf( "Podany plik  jest pusty.\n" );
            }
            stat(sciezka, &info);
            uid_t uid = info.st_uid;
            mode_t tryb = info.st_mode;
            if (tryb == S_IRWXU)
            {
                printf("Podany plik mozna modyfikowac i uruchomic\n");
            }
            else
                printf( "Podanego pliku nie mozna modyfikowac lub uruchomic\n" );
            printf( "ID wlasciciela : %d \n", uid );
            fclose( fptr );

            return 0;
        }





            /* Odblokowujemy semafor pierwszemu procesowi  */
            semunlock(semid1);


    }

    /* UWAGA! Procesy sa w nieskonczonej petli, wiec nie
     * usuwamy semaforow. Normalnie trzeba to jednak robic.
     reczne usuwanie semaforow - ipcrm -s ID_SEMAFORA*/
    semctl(semid1, 0, IPC_RMID, ctl);
    semctl(semid2, 0, IPC_RMID, ctl);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is giving errors in semaphore operations. Also, it seems to be reading data before writing. So there is a problem in synchronization. Since there are only two processes, you may try using just one semaphore for mutual exclusion of the shared memory segment.

Answer (score 0):

Although they are mostly reasonable, I see these issues with your semaphore and shared memory usage:

- you do not remove the shared memory segment when you have finished with it.
- the initial process may remove one or both semaphores before the child process is done using them.  Removal of System V semaphores is immediate, and this will cause concurrent and subsequent attempts at using those semaphores to fail.  I suspect that avoiding this is the intended purpose of the first semaphore, but to achieve that, the main process has to block on that semaphore before the removals, and the child has to unlock it before terminating.

Personally, I would also initialize both semaphores with value 0 instead of initializing them with value 1 and then decrementing them.

Additionally, you have an issue here:

> ```
>         char *sciezka;
>         printf("Data read from memory: %s\n",str);
>         strcpy(sciezka,str);
> ```

You are copying the data from the shared memory segment to the address specified by *uninitialized* pointer `sciezka`.  Undefined behavior results.

A pretty easy solution would be to use `strdup()` instead:

```
        sciezka = strdup(str);
```

Do be aware that this allocates memory for the duplicate, which the caller has responsibility to free when they no longer need it.

It is also a bit odd that you attempt to open the specified file before `stat()`ing it.  If you don't intend to read the file's contents then the `stat` function gives you more information about the file than you can get from opening it (or attempting to do so).  That including the file's length, which you instead compute via a different (valid) means.